# Sending Images from nodejs to Python script via standard input/output

Tags: javascript, python, node.js

I am trying to send an image from node js script to python script using python-shell. From what I know, I should use binary format.

I know that in python side I can use this 2 functions:

`import sys`

`sys.stdout.write()` and `sys.stdin.read()`

But I am not sure how the node js side gonna be? (Which functions can I use and how can I use them?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to write in the standard input/output (stdin/stoud) in nodejs you can use [process](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html) object [stdin](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_stdin) (a readable stream) and [stdout](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_stdout) (a writable stream) properties.

Example:

```
process.stdout.write('my output');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I tried it on sending a text for testing and it works.

Comment: But I tried it on image but it gave me invalid data error. Do you know if is it possible to send a png/jpeg images through this ??

Comment: Are you sending Buffer objects or plain texts? Maybe an encoding error.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to encode the image and send it but It did not work. So I used Socket programming instead and It worked wonderfully.